# Replacing a file inside a hidden folder via terminal

Tags: command-line, filemanager

I have a file in a `.directory` (so I can only see it through the terminal) and I have a file on the desktop with the same name.

How do I replace the file in the directory with the one on the desktop?

Comment: You can view hidden directories via file manager as well. Just press ctrl+h in file manager window

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**1. The console way**:

If you want to move/copy from .directory to the Desktop:

```
mv /path/to/.directory/filename ~/Desktop
cp /path/to/.directory/filename ~/Desktop
```

Alternatively, if you want to move/copy from the Desktop into .directory:

```
mv ~/Desktop/filename /path/to/.directory
cp ~/Desktop/filename /path/to/.directory
```

The difference between mv and cp is:

mv will move a file (the file at origin gets destroyed).

cp will copy a file (you get to keep the file at origin).

**2. The GUI way**:

Open your file manager and activate Show hidden files (Ctrl+H on PcManFM and many others). You can then navigate any hidden directories and drag and drop your file to its intended destination.

Comment: And he could use `cp/mv -iv`, interactive: prompt before overwrite, and verbose: explain what is being done.

Answer (score 0):

In Nautilus (Files) in the **View** menu, click **Show Hidden Files**, or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>. Then you can use the file manager, if you are not comfortable with the command line.